# Button "Next" in review actions

Tags: feature-request, review-page

When I want to see what is available under review I select "Close Votes" to take a look.

Then, the only actions there are:

[image]

But I have the next problems:

1. I am not a native English speaker and sometimes I can not really give myself the right to vote on specific questions (like voting "unclear" if the unclear thing for me is the language and not the post)
2. Some topics based for example on `MikTex` or similar, are not my dignity point and I don't want to participate in the voting about something I am not even familiar with.

The action that seems to be correct, is to press "Skip". But:

1. It doesn't appear again in my review actions (and if ,for example, I skipped just to give some more time to the op to edit, I would like to have the opportunity vote some hours or a day after)
2. If I don't press "Skip", I can not even see the next "under review" questions or answers.

I think a button (like "Next") to navigate inside the "under review" questions or answers is a useful addition that solves such problems.

Comment: While I understand your problem I don't think the next button would have much effect as there are probably many other people reviewing the item and some hours later most items won't be in the queue anymore.

Comment: @TeXnician, you are right, may be I haven't really understood the "skip" button or I am just affected by the way I solving many other problems. I mean, that If I want to have a fast look at close votes to find a post that already show added for review and I want to vote to remain open because I believe it has more things to offer than a supposed duplicate... Then, I have to "skip" some posts for some time, may be less than hours, but enough to give myself the opportunity read carefully and search  or translate etc for that other posts. If I skip them to find the first can not go back to them.

Comment: On-topic (but semi-trolling): You can feel what I mean if you read this post and place the cursor over the picture... Do you feel it? This is my feeling too in these cases... I just don't know where to click and I miss another button :P

Comment: The site is community driven, the community decides, you bbeing a part of that community. If others vote to close, the question will be put on hold. You have 7 days now to finish translating etc. and to vote to reopen. The chat squad will be happy to reopen. The review system, is a fast system, not to compare with reviewing a journal article.

Comment: @Johannes_B you are right at this... I can understand that review has to competed fast, but sometimes we just want to do the best of what our heart asking from us... And thus, we want to participate in community and keep our "conscience" as clear as we can. It is bad practice to close a post as unclear before giving the opportunity to the OP to rephrase or to make his request clear and I don't want voting for closing such posts... But if ten minutes after I show and decided to skip in such a post, OP will make clear his question... I would like to vote to remain open...

Comment: I checked my history.vall questions reviewed and voted to stay open were closed in the end. Not much we can do here.